# Помогите разобраться с пунктуацией вокруг "это"

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите с пунктуацией в предложении. Я не понимаю как правильно и по какому правилу.

Варианты:
1) В 2005 году исполнителю пришло письмо от фаната из России, по словам Молли, это захватывало.
2)В 2005 году исполнителю пришло письмо от фаната из России, по словам Молли: "это захватывало".
3)В 2005 году исполнителю пришло письмо от фаната из России, по словам Молли, это – захватывало.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По всей видимости, относительно *первого* варианта (два другие перенасыщены пунктуацией) достаточно изменить знак после "России": в этом месте разделяются два законченных высказывания, и при чтении нужна пауза. Если не ставить точку, то для усиления логической связи этих двух частей можно поставить в этом месте *точку с запятой или тире*. Кавычки при имеющейся цитате не обязательны: на эти два слова ссылаются явным указанием "по словам", а после них предложение заканчивается, - границы и точность переданного очевидны, а стилю автора эти слова не противоречат. Кавычки были бы полезны при ссылке на нестандартное или эмоциональное высказывание ("это было круто"), от которого автор хотел бы отмежеваться.

Answer (score 1):

**В 2005 году исполнителю пришло письмо от фаната из России; по словам Молли, это захватывало.**

Но хотелось бы заметить, что глагол несов. вида "захватывало" говорит о продолжительном действии, в то время как "письмо пришло"(сов. вид) — короткое событие. 
Следовало бы подумать, каким словом заменить "захватывало". Возможно, Молли говорил не об одном письме, а о некоем потоке писем, но без контекста можно только гадать.